# Responding to "Clear history when Firefox closes" in Firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, exit

For security reasons, I need to clear my addon's data whenever Firefox's browsing history is cleared. To do this, I am listening for the "browser:purge-session-history" event, which is correctly fired when the user clicks the History->Clear-Recent-History menu option.

However, this event does NOT fire when the "Clear history when Firefox closes" settings option is enabled, though the browser history is successfully cleared on exit. How can I handle this case?

Answer (score 4):

in main.js::onUnload you can check the value of the following preference:

```
exports.onUnload = function(reason) {

    var val = require("sdk/preferences/service").get("privacy.sanitize.sanitizeOnShutdown");              
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this awesome info with us!